# Using custom compare function for list sort within a class

Tags: c++

There seems to be an issue with using a member function when i want to create a custom compare for the std::list function sort. I'm getting the following errors:

> Error C3867   'my_class::cmp': non - standard syntax; use '&' to create
>   a pointer to member
>   Error C2660   'std::list>::sort': function does
>   not take 1 arguments

Below is the code to reproduce the error

```
#include <list>

class my_class {
    std::list<int> container;
public:
    bool cmp(const int& a, const int& b) {
        return a < b;
    }

    void push(int e) {
        container.push_back(e);
        container.sort(cmp);
    }
};


int main()
{

    my_class my_c;
    return 0;
}
```

Not really sure why im getting the errors. If i do this outside a class it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

C++ reference [reads](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort):

> `comp` - comparison function object ... . The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> `bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);`

Your `cmp()` is a member function and doesn't have this signature. Loosely speaking, it takes three arguments, not two, the first one being an object (`*this`).

To make `.sort()` happy, make `cmp()` a static member function:

```
static bool cmp(const int& a, const int& b) {
    return a < b;
}
```

Static member functions do not need objects to be called. So, it has the desired signature, and your code should compile.

If you want to use a non-static member function as a comparator, the easiest way is to use a lambda:

```
container.sort([this](const int& a, const int& b) { return cmp(a, b); });
```

Note how we explicitly capture `this` pointer that will then be used (implicitly) to invoke `cmp`.

Instead of `const int&` you can use just `int`. It has small size and there is no sense to pass it by reference.